# How to extract text from multiple div class using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to get text class price-value from [Page_inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMp5l.png)

Used driver.find_element_by_xpath and WebDriverWait.

```
rateText=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[starts-with(@class,"price")]//div[contains(@class,"price-value")]')))
for ratevalue in rateText:
      print (ratevalue.text)
```

result not found :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\project\totempop\webscraping\asrPOP.py", line 22, in 
> rateText=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[starts-with(@class,"price")]//div[contains(@class,"price-value")]')))
> File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have the problem with XPath. You should try this one: './/div[contains(@class,"price-value")]/text()'

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "price-value")))
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "price-value")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close enough but you need some minor adjustments as follows:

- The *`<div class="price">`* have a single classname value, so you can drop the *`contains()`* part.
- The *`<strong class="price-value">`* is within the parent *`<div>`*, so you have to adjust the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver).
- Ideally to get text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.price div.price-line > strong.price-value"))).text)
    ```
  - Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='price']//div[@class='price-line']/strong[@class='price-value']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: its work, thanks bro